# Problem with django's url template tag (and reverse() function)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have the following view function in *activities.views*:

```
def activity_thumbnail(request, id):
  pass
```

I'm trying to get the URL for that view in one of my templates.
When I try the following:

```
{% url activities.views.activity_thumbnail latest_activity.id %}
```

I get the following error:

> Caught an exception while rendering:
>   Reverse for ''
>   with arguments '(449L,)' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found.

I get the same kind of error when I try the following:

```
{% url activities.views.activity_thumbnail request,latest_activity.id %}
```

When I  try named parameters:

```
{% url activities.views.activity_thumbnail id=r.latest_activity.key.id %}
```

I get:

> Caught an exception while rendering:
>   Reverse for ''
>   with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{'id': 449L}' not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't define `activity_thumbnail` in your `urls.py`

```
urls.py:

from views import activity_thumbnail
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^activity_thumbnail/$', activity_thumbnail, name='activity_thumbnail')
)
```

That might seem a bit redundant, but it gives you more freedom in mapping your views into urls.